# Запомнить объект для запросов в рамках одной сессии в Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, boot

Как использовать объекты с сохраненным состоянием в рамках одной сессии, без сохранения объекта в бд? Сервис написан на Java. Spring boot.

Comment: Как угодно можно использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

обычно в метод как аргумент добавляют `HttpSession session` - сессию и сохраняют в нем объект через вызов метода `session.setAttribute(key, value);`

,если объектов много, то создать статичную map-у

```
static Map<String, HttpSession> connectedUsers;
```